# How do I prevent the escape key from closing an alert in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, alert

Attaching a keydown/keyup event listener to the stage and trying to stop the even this way doesn't work. Any working methods?

Comment: I don't think key events are cancellable; so the I thought `preventDefault()` has no affect.  Have you tried to do this with a close handler?  IF that doesn't work, I think you'll have to extend the Alert class, or possibly the PopUpManager class.  Based on a 5 minute code review it is not obvious to me where the escape key comes in.

Comment: Brilliant. Just solved this by adding a cancel button (along with the yes and no buttons), and now the Escape key triggers the cancel button, which I can handle properly in the CloseEvent. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Great; be sure to post your solution as a formal answer to your own question.

Comment: Wanted to accept your answer as the solution, but can't seem to find the checkmark next to it - sorry, I'm new to SO. Seems like being a newbie I can't answer my own question for the next 6 hours either :)

Comment: I didn't give a formal answer, which is why there is no checkbox.  I just provided a comment.  since I only nudged you in a direction, I strongly suggest you answer your own question with full details.

Comment: Oh I see. Will do that, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding a cancel button (along with the yes and no buttons), and now pressing the escape key triggers the cancel button, which I can handle properly in the CloseEvent. Would be nice to be able to do this without actually showing the cancel button, but this works as a solution for me. Thanks to Reboog711 for the tip!